# Install Scribus 1.5 On Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, ppa, scribus

All HOWTOs I found how to install scribus 1.5 are only for Ubuntu 14.04 or 15.04, but on 14.10 I cannot find the package scribus-trunk in the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scribus/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scribus-trunk
```

How do I install scribus-trunk on Ubuntu 14.10?

Comment: Note that 14.10 is [EOL since Jul 2015](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2015-July/000197.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The packet `scribus-trunk` doesn't seem to be in the 14.10 ppa repository, but you can install the 14.04 ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scribus/ppa
sudo sed -i s/utopic/trusty/g /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scribus-ubuntu-ppa-utopic.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scribus-trunk
```

---

Note:
On High resolution screens you need to start scribus-trunk with a [resollution switcher](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/4589d7352631542a1ffb)

Comment: Some CMYK Profiles were replaced, for example **ISO Coated v2 300% (ECI)** replaced by: **Fogra27L CMYK Coated Press**, don't know if thats caused by the wrong release or if it is normal at first start.

Comment: Very good answer +1

Answer (score 2):

Now `scribus-trunk` is no longer available for 14.04, but you can install the `scribus-ng` package to download scribus 1.5.2:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scribus/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scribus-ng
```

Comment: Please can state the steps for noobs :)

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen done!